# Can the possible groups by determined by hand?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose, $G$ is a group of order $12$ containing an element $a$ with order $4$. Can I show the following facts by hand ?

- The group is either cyclic or isomorphic to the group $C3:C4$
- $a^2$ is the only element in the group with order $2$

Cauchy's theorem tells us that there is at least an element with order $2$ 
and at least an element with order $3$. If $b$ has order $3$, is it correct
to claim $$G=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,b,ba,ba^2,ba^3,b^2,b^2a,b^2a^2,b^2a^3\},$$ and 
if yes, does this help to show the facts above ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by doing this by hand. Also, what do you mean the the group $C_3 : C_4$?

Comment: GAP displays this group-structure for the non-abelian group with order $12$ and an element with order $4$. "By hand" means : without a computer program and without exhaustive trial and error.

Comment: Well, then look up in GAP what it means.

Comment: I did not find it in the GAP-manual, but in the site group-props : $C3:C4$ is the dicyclic group $Dic12$

Comment: Look in the documentation for the StructureDescription method.

Comment: The presentation given in the site is $<a,b,c|a^3=b^2=c^2=abc>$. Does that mean we need at least $3$ generators ?

Comment: What site? What did it say when you looked in that documentation? It has a clear description of what the notation means. And no, if the group has an element of order $4$ then it should be easy to see that it is generated by two elements.

Comment: I can certainly prove those statements without using a computer. I have no idea whether you can. How could I possibly know that? Have you tried?

Comment: What about the claim in the question : G=[...] ; Is it true ?

Comment: @Peter: G=[...]; this is OK. But this doesn't says much about structure of G. For example, what is order of $ba$? It has different possiblities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show it with Sylow's theorems. Let $\langle b\rangle$ be a Sylow-$3$ subgroup. The number of Sylow-$3$ subgroups is $\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and it divides $12$; it is $1$ or $4$.

*Suppose Sylow-$3$ subgroup is not normal* (so there should be $4$ Sylow-$3$ subgroups); collect their non-identity elements, we cover $8$ elements of order $3$.

What about remaining $4$ elements? There is already a subgroup of order $4$, and hence we should have unique subgroup of order $4$; so $\langle a\rangle$ is unique (so normal) subgroup of order $4$. This forces that $a^2$ is the unique element of order $2$ (*wait! proof is incomplete*), hence it is in the center of $G$.

Take product of this central element of order $2$ with elements of order $3$; we get elements of order $6$. This leads a contradiction, since we have

$$\mbox{($8$ elements of order $3$) +($4$ elements of order dividing $4$)+some elements of order $6$ }$$
this is exceeding $|G|$.

Hence, the Sylow-$3$ subgroup is normal, hence unique. This proves first bullet in question depending on whether subgroup of order $4$ is unique or non-unique.

We already proved that $\langle b\rangle$ is unique subgroup of order $3$, so $\langle b\rangle\trianglelefteq G$. Then we have $a\langle b\rangle a^{-1}=\langle b\rangle$. But then what is $aba^{1-}$? It is member in $\{1,b,b^2\}$ and $aba^{-1}$ can not be $1$ (why?)

If $aba^{-1}=b$ then $ab=ba$, so $G$ becomes cyclic group of order $12$; it contains unique element of order $2$.

If $aba^{-1}=b^2$ then $a^2ba^{-2}=(b^2)^2=b$; so $a^2$ commues with $b$ (and obviously with $a$). Hence $a^2$ is central element of order $2$.

Suppose, there is another element $c$ of order $2$. Then, since $a^2$ is central, $a^2$ with $c$ will form a Klein-4 group of order $4$; it is Sylow-$2$ subgroup. But hypothesis says that the Sylow-$2$ subgroup is cyclic, a contradiction. Thus $a^2$ is unique element of order $2$.

---

Another way to show uniqueness of element of order $2$.

$\langle a^2\rangle$ is a given subgroup of order $2$, and is contained in a cyclic subgroup $H=\langle a\rangle$ of order $4$. Suppose $c$ is another element of order $2$. Then $\langle c\rangle$, being a $2$-subgroup, must be contained in a Sylow-$2$ subgroup, say $K$. Since $K$ is conjugate to $H$, $K$ is cyclic. Then $H\cap K=1$, hence $|HK|=\frac{|H|.|K|}{|H\cap K|}=4.4/1>|G|$, a contradiction. Thus,

> If $|G|=12$ and if $G$ contains an element of order $4$, then $G$ contains unique element of order $2$.

Comment: Another way of handling four Sylow $3$-subgroups is to consider the action by conjugation of $G$ on those subgroups. This has to have order $4$ and so must by $A_4$. So $G \cong A_4$, but $A_4$ does not have a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup.